# R - Finding the first element/position in a vector satisfying an inequality, for each element in a vector

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector *Y*. If I want to know where *Y* is greater than 4, I can use something like `which(Y>4)`, something with the function `Position`, etc. However, now I have a vector *X* for which I want to obtain a vector with elements `which(Y>x)` for each element *x* of *X*. I could do this with a loop, but for the large vectors *X* I want to apply this on, this is very inefficient.

What is a more efficient, vectorised way of achieving what I want?

Comment: `sapply(X, function(x) which(Y > x))` ?

Comment: Is `sapply` faster than `apply`? I found no difference between the latter and a for loop, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function `outer` from the `base` package:

If you want a list of all indices that satisfy `Y > X[i]`:

```
## Test data:
Y <- c(3,6,7,2,9,6,12,5,2,8)
X <- c(4,6,8)

indicesList <- apply(X = outer(Y, X, '>'), MARGIN = 2, FUN = which)

> indicesList
[[1]]
[1]  2  3  5  6  7  8 10

[[2]]
[1]  3  5  7 10

[[3]]
[1] 5 7
```

If you just want to find the first element in `Y` satisfying `Y > X[i]`:

```
firstIndicesVec <- apply(X = outer(Y, X, '>'), MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) min(which(x)))

> firstIndicesVec
[1] 2 3 5
```